# Programmatic Execution of the "fipsinstall" Command

Tags: openssl

I am currently working on a project that involves the use of the "fipsinstall" command, and I'm exploring the possibility of running it programmatically. I would appreciate some guidance on the steps involved and whether this approach is feasible.

- Has anyone successfully executed the "fipsinstall" command
  programmatically?
- What steps need to be taken to achieve programmatic
  execution of "fipsinstall"?
- Are there any potential challenges or    considerations that I should
  be aware of?

I'm eager to hear from anyone with experience or insights into this matter. Your assistance will be invaluable in helping me navigate through this aspect of my project.

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise!